# mac terminal shortcut not working

Tags: macos, terminal

I intend to set up mac terminal shortcut per instructions but it does not work. This is what I did:

open terminal

```
nano .bash-profile
#add a few aliases
alias dtt = 'do this thing'
alias gc='git commit -m' 
#save the bash profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Afterwards the new alias are present in the bash file. However no autocomplete is present in terminal, if I type dtt, it won't change to 'do this thing'. The shortcut doesn't seem to work.

Anything amiss? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alias is used to do something (in your ex. 'do this thing'), typing the command you chose ('dtt'). The terminal won't autocomplete anything.
In fact alias instructs the shell to replace one string with another when executing commands.
You could use it to abbreviate commands. e.g. alias pg="ping". If you type pg google.com it will exec "ping google.com"

Comment: Does omitting the spaces around the '=' help?

Comment: thanks @Carlo Federico Vescovo I realized alias doesn't auto-complete just now. so for the frequent comments which share part of the syntax and has other part of syntax varying case-by-case,such as git commit -m 'the message here varies'. is there a good way to shortcut it?  this example might be too short/simple, but just as a demo for more complex commands.

Comment: Yes, it is! E.g. you could set an alias "gc"="git commit -m" and use it in this way: gc "your commit message"